# 32-bit Windows app: storing buffers in 64-bit executable, with 'good' performance

Tags: c++, windows

I have a 32-bit app, which is difficult to convert to 64-bit due to 3rd party dependencies that are 32-bit only.

My application needs to process several large buffers.  I was wondering if there was a way for my app to send those buffers to a 64-bit executable, which would store a queue of those buffers, and my app could request a few of those buffers at a time so it can process them.

I have some similar things using boost intercommunication, but I'm not sure what the performance penalty is for this.  What would be the highest performance way to achieve this?

[Edit - the purpose of using the 64-bit app for 'storage' is so it can store more than 4GB of memory]

Comment: What does this have to do with "storing"?

Comment: The only way to know the performance cost is to measure it with your specific circumstances.  Things that will affect it are what the underlying transport mechanism is, how large the buffers are, how frequently they're sent, how they're sent, and how they're received.  I doubt anyone on SO can give you a satisfactory answer.

Comment: im nearly certain there would be no benifit to do this. Do you think you can make a transport mechnanism in under 32bits of overhead?

Comment: The idea of 'storing' is, let's say, each buffer is 500MB, I could use the 64-bit executable to store 50 of them (which the 32-app couldn't, because of 4GB limitation).  Then, the 32-bit app can retrieve a single buffer and work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you want to do is be able to use more than 2 or 3 GB of memory from your program even though it is a 32 bit program. If that's the case, consider creating an anonymous memory mapped file (using [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and using mappings there as your buffers instead. Unmap them when you're not using them and they stop consuming address space, but on x64 operating systems the OS is perfectly capable of keeping the buffers in RAM rather than paging them out.

If that's not what you're trying to do, then I'd ask what you want the 64 bit process for in the first place.

Comment: This is indeed what I am trying to do.  So I wouldn't need a 64-bit app at all?